# How to use node-geocoder along with proxy in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, geocoder

I have my `node.js` server running on a vm along with a proxy on it. Now i am using `node-geocoder` to get `lat` `lng` from `node-geocoder` like this

```
const NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');
var geocoder = NodeGeocoder(constants.config.geocoderOptions);


const geoCodeAddress = await geocoder.geocode(address.location);
```

now it's throwing an error due to proxy like this

```
 'request to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&key=my-key&address=Korangi%20Creek failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND maps.googleapis.com maps.googleapis.com:443'
```

So how can i pass my proxy settings in `node-geocoder` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your options for NodeGeocoder use:

```
httpAdapter: "request"
```

This is instead of the `http` or `https` options listed in the docs.

Reference: https://github.com/nchaulet/node-geocoder/issues/190

This answer assumes you already have your proxy variables set in your standard setup (so doing `curl example.com` from terminal returns expected output). If you don't have proxy env variables set you will need to configure that first.